# SQL Server for XML mix Element and dynamic Attribute

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, attributes, element

Not able to to get the desired XML output, when I execute the code below I dont want the tag amount, I need the amount as a value from vCod tag.

Can I get that ouput with FOR XML? what am I doing wrong ?

This code sql code :

```sql
declare @t table (vKey int,  vCod varchar(4) , amount decimal(16,2) )

insert @t values ( 1 , 'v110' , 12.34 )
insert @t values ( 1 , 'v115' , 18.40 )
insert @t values ( 1 , 'v120' , 2.55 )
insert @t values ( 2 , 'v110' , 22.33 )
insert @t values ( 2 , 'v120' , 8.05 )
insert @t values ( 3 , 'v120' , 13.23 )
insert @t values ( 3 , 'v125' , 28.05 )
insert @t values ( 3 , 'v130' , 44.00 )

select vkey as '@key', vCod as '@vCod' , amount as '@amount' from @t for xml 
path('Root')`
```

Produces:

```xml
<Root key="1" vCod="v110" amount="12.34" />
<Root key="1" vCod="v115" amount="18.40" />
<Root key="1" vCod="v120" amount="2.55" />
<Root key="2" vCod="v110" amount="22.33" />
<Root key="2" vCod="v120" amount="8.05" />
<Root key="3" vCod="v120" amount="13.23" />
<Root key="3" vCod="v125" amount="28.05" />
<Root key="3" vCod="v130" amount="44.00" />
```

I need this:

```xml
<Root>
    <Group key="1">
        <vCod v110="12.24"
              v115="18.40"
              v120="2.55"/>
    </Group>
    <Group key="2">
        <vCod v110="22.33"
              v120="8.05"/>
    </Group>
    <Group key="3">
        <vCod v120="13.23"
              v125="28.05"
              v130="44.00"/>
    </Group>
</Root>
```

Comment: Have you tried to pivot the amounts around the vCod values?

Comment: group by vKey and cast to xml the string_agg(vCod + amount) of each vKey: `select k.vKey as "Group/@key",
(select cast('<vCod ' +string_agg(concat(c.vCod, '="', c.amount, '"'), ' ') + ' />' as xml)
from @t as c
where c.vKey = k.vKey) as 'Group/node()'
from @t as k
group by k.vKey
for xml path('Root')`

Comment: @lptr why so many `Root` elements?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning..lt’s easy to change to `for xml path(''), root('Root')` ..but it’s better to have an “incorrect” answer in comments..otherwise one might get suspended

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) the `amount` values around `vCod` so that you can use those `vCod` values as attribute names, e.g.:

```sql
declare @t table (vKey int,  vCod varchar(4) , amount decimal(16,2) )

insert @t values ( 1 , 'v110' , 12.34 )
insert @t values ( 1 , 'v115' , 18.40 )
insert @t values ( 1 , 'v120' , 2.55 )
insert @t values ( 2 , 'v110' , 22.33 )
insert @t values ( 2 , 'v120' , 8.05 )
insert @t values ( 3 , 'v120' , 13.23 )
insert @t values ( 3 , 'v125' , 28.05 )
insert @t values ( 3 , 'v130' , 44.00 )

select
  vkey as [@key],
  v110 as [vCod/@v110],
  v115 as [vCod/@v115],
  v120 as [vCod/@v120],
  v125 as [vCod/@v125],
  v130 as [vCod/@v130]
from (
  select vKey, vCod, amount from @t
) Src
pivot (max(amount) for vCod in ([v110], [v115], [v120], [v125], [v130])) p
for xml path('Group'), root('Root');
```

Which produces:

```xml
<Root>
    <Group key="1">
        <vCod v110="12.34" v115="18.40" v120="2.55"/>
    </Group>
    <Group key="2">
        <vCod v110="22.33" v120="8.05"/>
    </Group>
    <Group key="3">
        <vCod v120="13.23" v125="28.05" v130="44.00"/>
    </Group>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Charlieface, you're quite right to point out that string literals as column names got deprecated in SQL Server 2016, ref: [Deprecated Database Engine features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016).